# Chrome App web view using Fullscreen & Alwaysontop

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a Chrome app that opens up using the web view and loads our webpage. I'm trying to make a app that will lock down the web view so when someone is taking a test they can't get out of it or use something else to try and cheat. So the issue I'm having right now is I can't get the Full screen and AlwaysOnTop to work with each other. Is there a way to do this or will these two things not work together and if not is there a hack to get them to work or maybe another direction I need to take. I'm currently running my app with the Chrome Beta since alwaysOnTop doesn't work with the stable version yet. Here is the code in my 
main.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('browser.html', {
      state: "fullscreen",
     "resizable": false,
     'alwaysOnTop': true
   }, 

  function(win) {
    win.contentWindow.document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 27){
           e.preventDefault();
    }
   });
   win.contentWindow.document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 27){
           e.preventDefault();
    }
    });
   });
  });
```

Any help or some type of direction would be great. I've only been able to get the alwaysontop to work when setting bounds instead but this will display the minimize maximize and exit which kind of defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to have a look at the "overrideEscFullscreen" permission.
See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/test/data/extensions/platform_apps/prevent_leave_fullscreen_old/manifest.json&q=overrideEscFullscreen&sq=package:chromium&type=cs

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test app for leaving fullscreen rules",
  "version": "1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "fullscreen", "overrideEscFullscreen"
  ]
}
```

main.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('main.html', {}, function(win) {
    // The following key events handler will prevent the default behavior for
    // the ESC key, thus will prevent the ESC key to leave fullscreen.
    win.contentWindow.document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
    win.contentWindow.document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm using that in the code I provided. I change what happens when the esc key is pressed so they can't exit full screen. The thing I'm trying to achieve with the always on top is if they press alt-tab to goto a different window or press the window key to open show the start bar in windows 7 they can open another application. Im trying to use the always on top so when they do perform those steps and try to open something it will open it in the back and they won't be able to use it.

Comment: Sorry for late response but Im unaware what you mean hiding/showing?